# What is meant by homogeneous in $x$ in $n$'th degree?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, terminology, definition, mathematics

I'm reading about classical mechanics by Goldstein, and in the section about Hamiltonian mechanics it is stated that in the expression:

$$H(q,p,t)=\dot{q}_ip_i-L(q,\dot{q}, t)$$

the Lagrangian function $L$ can be braken down into three components:

$$L=L_0(q_i,t) + L_1(q_i, t)\dot{q}_k + L_2(q_i,t)\dot{q}_k\dot{q}_m$$

(no sum on $i$ in the square brackets) where $L_0$ is the part of the
 Lagrangian that is independent of the generalized velocities, $L_1$
 represents the coefficients of the part of the Lagrangian that is
 homogeneous in $\dot{q}_i$ in the first degree, and $L_2$ is the part
 that is homogeneous in $\dot{q}_i$ in the second degree.

It is not fully clear to me what is meant by:

> $L_1$ represents the coefficients of the part of the Lagrangian that is
>   homogeneous in $\dot{q}_i$ in the first degree, and $L_2$ is the part
>   that is homogeneous in $\dot{q}_i$ in the second degree.

What does these mean ? Mathematical definition? The book is not so clear on these definitions

Comment: Suggested reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question? We can migrate it if you like, but there may be a duplicate there already.

Comment: Thank you @rob no matter for me if you migrate it. I thought about the wiki-site, but I wasn't sure about it. Seems like the term "homogeneous" is used in many contexts and meanings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else bumps into the same question, I think I found the answer:

> The Euler's theorem states that if $f$ is a homogeneous function of
>   degree $n$ in the variables $x_i$, then
>
> $$\sum_i x_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=nf.$$

So for example, if $f$ is a function of two variables $x_1, x_2$ and it is homogeneous, say to 3rd degree, in these variables, then:

$$x_1\frac{\partial f(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_1}+x_2\frac{\partial f(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_2}=3f(x_1, x_2).$$